# Only allow UILongPressGestureRecognizer on parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

### Problem

I need to ensure that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is only applied to the parent view and doesn't get called when I long press on a child view - I should also note that setting the child view variable `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false is not an option in my case as the child view requires a tap gesture for other purposes.

### My code so far (pretty basic):

*(Notice when you run it how the long press gesture is also triggered when long pressing over the subview - I want the long press to only be triggered if the user is pressing on the main/ parent view)*

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let smallView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    view.addSubview(smallView)
    
    let longPressMultiSelection = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))
    longPressMultiSelection.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressMultiSelection)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    if sender?.view == self.view {
        switch sender?.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            print("here")
        case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
            print("ended")
        default:
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Where is this "child view" of which you speak? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. It is added as a subview of backdropView.

Comment: Don't say "sorry"; _fix_ it by editing the question. Copy and paste your _real code_ from your _real app_ into the question. This is _all about_ the child view and you omit it from the code?? How are we supposed to help you with the code if you don't _show_ the code?

Comment: I was just editing it then. It should be there now.

Comment: What should happen if the user does long press on the child view? Do you want the long press to "fall through" to the backdrop view, or should just nothing happen?

Comment: Nothing should happen if the user is long pressing on the child view. An event should only be triggered if long pressing on the parent view/ backdrop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the gesture recognizer delegate, so use your mighty delegate powers to decide whether the gesture recognizer should operate:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    !smallView.bounds.contains(gestureRecognizer.location(in: smallView))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems so obvious now that I think about it. I have refined the code a little to handle cases where there could perhaps be more than one child view that should not trigger the long press gesture.

Comment: Certainly. Plus I omitted any check as to what gesture recognizer this is, etc. I just wanted to show you the basic principle, which is to say what you mean: if the gesture is inside the forbidden view, then don't recognize the gesture.